# Autofac Scanning Assemblies for certain class type

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, autofac

I've started using `Autofac` and want to scan some DLL's and get `Autofac` to register some of the classes within them.

The classes that I'm interested in all inherit from a PluginBase class but the below code doesn't seem to be registering them.  Can anyone help?

```
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();


        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(PluginBase))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .AsSelf();

        var container = builder.Build();
        var pluginClasses = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<PluginBase>>();

        //pluginClasses is empty!!!!
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you need to specify the base class of your Plugins on registration. The call **AsImplementedInterfaces** registers the type with its implemented interfaces and not by its base type. You should update your registration to register your plugins as PluginBase.

Here´s the code:

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();


    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
        .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(PluginBase))
        .As<PluginBase>();

    var container = builder.Build();
    var pluginClasses = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<PluginBase>>();
```

Comment: That works! Could I add the AsImplementedInterfaces for newer classes that do implement interfaces?

Comment: I think these two calls should work together. Then the type gets registered with by its base type and all interfaces it implements.

Comment: Oops, just re-read what I wrote and doesn't make sense. If I have a class that inherits from PluginBase and has a constructor argument of an interface this won't work even with AsImplementedInterfaces. Do I do a new builder registration or can I amend the current code?

Comment: I just got it working by calling RegisterAssemblyTypes again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a note, you don't need the `Where` call if you use `As`.

Comment: That does not works when assembly are not loaded. AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies is only returns loaded assemblies.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe do is this way:

```
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces()
        .Any(i => i.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (IDependency))))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

In this code I use `IDependency` as a marker interface. You may replace it with your `PluginBase` class and remove `Where` method.

The point is to use [`IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) method.

Comment: Will that allow for classes that don't implement interfaces and those that do? I'm working with legacy code so old stuff wont have interfaces but new stuff will

Comment: It should work with `Where(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(PluginBase))`. If not, I'll try to help you.

Comment: Of course remove `.AsImplementedInterfaces()`. I didn't notice this line.

Comment: That doesn't work either. PluginBase is abstract if that helps

Comment: If I put my original code back and just take out the where clause it works

Comment: Are the classes that extends `PluginBase` in your current AppDomain?

Comment: Yes they are. Jehof's seems to be getting somewhere but I still stuck

Answer (score 0):

Pls, note that you shouldn't use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` due to an issue related to restarting IIS.

> When hosting applications in IIS all assemblies are loaded into the
> AppDomain when the application first starts, **but when the AppDomain is
> recycled by IIS the assemblies are then only loaded on demand**.

To avoid this issue use the [GetReferencedAssemblies()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getreferencedassemblies.aspx) method on [System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.aspx) to get a list of the referenced assemblies instead:

```
var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>();
```

That will force the referenced assemblies to be loaded into the `AppDomain` immediately making them available for module scanning.

For more detail, you can read here: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/iis-restart.html