# Autofac not resolving registered types

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am registering my components/services as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9159703/84539) and I am also implementing a class as shown below.  When I call Reload, its saying its not registered and I know it is. Any ideas?

```
public interface ITypeReloader 
{ 
    PluginBase Reload(Type type); 
} 

public class TypeReloader 
{ 
    IComponentContext _container; 
    public TypeReloader(IComponentContext container) 
    { 
        _container = container; 
    } 

    public PluginBase Reload(Type type) 
    { 
        (PluginBase)_container.Resolve(type);  //Not registered error
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you link to uses `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` to get the currently loaded assemblies, and then registers any types derived from `PluginBase` in them.

However, assemblies are only loaded into an AppDomain when first needed. I bet the types you are interested in reside in assemblies **which have not yet been loaded when you do the registration.** You can check this by looking the result of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`: is it missing any assemblies you were expecting to be there?

The easiest way to fix this is by using the [AutoFac MEF integration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MefIntegration) and MEF's DirectoryCatalog instead. The DirectoryCatalog is designed exactly for this scenario.

**edit**: on a second look, the problem is that you register as `PluginBase` but then try to resolve as some subtype. For what you are trying to achieve here, you probably need to register `.AsSelf()` instead of `.As<PluginBase>()`.

Comment: It's not missing any. I know it has registered classes they inherit pluginbase as I can call resolve pluginbase and it gives me various instances

Comment: I kept the registration the same but added AsSelf and it seems to have worked! So it has As<PluginBase>().AsSelf()

Comment: Not sure what that means though!

Comment: @Jon: Let's say that you have a type `FooPlugin` derived from `PluginBase`. In that case, `As<PluginBase>().AsSelf()` means that  you have registered it as both `PluginBase` *and* `FooPlugin`. You can then use either of these types when you call `Resolve`.