# How to register type as specific interface by scanning local exe or assembly

Tags: c#, autofac

I understand that i can use reflection to scan and register components? Is this what it called scanning in the help/wiki?

```
  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
  builder.RegisterType<GeneralHtmlNotifier>().As<INotifier>();
  builder.RegisterType<DiskSystemNotifier>().As<INotifier>();
  builder.RegisterType<DatabaseSizesNotifier>().As<INotifier>();
  builder.RegisterType<GeneralTextFileNotifier>().As<INotifier>();
  builder.RegisterType<DiskSystemTextNotifier>().As<INotifier>();
  builder.RegisterType<DatabaseSizesTextNotifier>().As<INotifier>();
  builder.RegisterType<DiskSystemHierarchyNotifier>().As<INotifier>();
  builder.RegisterType<DatabaseSizeHierarchyNotifier>().As<INotifier>();
  builder.Build();
```

I want to "scan" my local exe for INotifier and register. Don't really understand how I call write the code.

```
 var dataAccess = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
 .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Is this what i'm looking for.

Comment: does this help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159277/autofac-scanning-assemblies-for-certain-class-type?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use in general, so it makes sure to implement specific interface and gets rid of abstract classes (if any):

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
         .Where(t => (typeof(INotifier).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract))
         .AsSelf()
         .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```