# Dependency injection code level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm having a problem in concept wise and c# coding level about dependency injection. Up to now I know we can use unity or autofac for resolving dependencies. But i'm having a problem in my code, whether this is correct or not.

Project has 4 layers.

1. Web project
2. Service level
3. Repository level
4. Entities

This is my MVC controller level code (in Web project)

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;

    public EmployeeController() : this(new EmployeeService())
    {


    }

    public EmployeeController(IEmployeeService employeeService)
    {
        _employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    public ActionResult EmployeeList()
    {
        try
        {
            EmployeeVM empVM;
            List<EmployeeVM> lstEmpVM = new List<ViewModel.EmployeeVM>();
            var empList = _employeeService.GetAllEmployeeList();

            //below foreach use to map domain object to viewmodel object.

            foreach (var item in empList)
            {
                empVM = new EmployeeVM();
                empVM.EmployeeId = item.EmployeeId;
                empVM.Department = item.Department;
                empVM.FirstName = item.FirstName;
                empVM.LastName = item.LastName;
                empVM.Permenent = item.Permanent;
                lstEmpVM.Add(empVM);
            }

            return View(lstEmpVM);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

This is my **EmployeeService** service level code (In service level)

```
public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
{
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _empRepository;

    public EmployeeService() : this(new EmployeeRepository())
    {

    }


    public EmployeeService(IEmployeeRepository empRepository)
    {
        _empRepository = empRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAllEmployeeList()
    {
        try
        {
            var ObjEmpList = _empRepository.GetEmployees();
            return ObjEmpList;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }

    //Some logical code going here

}
```

This is the Interface of EmployeeService

```
public interface IEmployeeService
{
    IEnumerable<Employee> GetAllEmployeeList();

}
```

There is a repository, which connect with data layer same as above coding.

Please tell me my above code is OK with dependency injection or I should have to change any of code? Actually I have no any proper I idea, these modules are properly decoupled or not.

Comment: Just remove the default parameter-less constructors from `EmployeeController` and `EmployeeService` classes and your code is good for DI. With those default constructors you currently have coupling between the different layers and specific implementations of your dependencies. It should be the responsibility of the DI framework to inject specific implementations into the services.

Comment: If you are actually using Unity or Autofac in the project then you don't need Default constructors of any of the above classes. Given that the dependencies are configured properly they will be resolved at run time without you worrying about it.

Comment: If i'm not going to use unity or autofac, really I can't do my project with DI?

Comment: @weeraa - If you don't want to use a container, you can use [pure DI](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2014/11/18/how-to-use-pure-di/). The container is completely optional - but you still need to tie into whatever framework you are using the correct extension point so that the dependencies are resolved from the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). In MVC, that can be either `IControllerFactory` or `IDependencyResolver`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those default constructor..
Somewhere in the code you need to register you classes/interface in the dependency container autofac..., may be in global.ascx. can you provide that code...?

You can also to that by scanning you assembly as show in the this link
[Autofac Scanning Assemblies for certain class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159277/autofac-scanning-assemblies-for-certain-class-type)

Comment: Actually still i'm not implemented actofac resolver. I just want check does my code is ok with DI?

Answer (score 0):

As Darin mentioned in his comment.  Per the code you provided, just remove the parameterless constructor that you provided for.  So delete all the constructors that look like this

```
        public EmployeeController() : this(new EmployeeService())
        {
        }
```

This is considered [Poor man's DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/)

To achieve what you want with a container you need to 
1. replace the controller factory with one that is container aware.
2. register all your interfaces/implementing classes with the container

So for 1.  you need to do this (all examples use Windsor, but the concepts are the same)

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    // Fields
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    // Methods
    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        if (kernel == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("kernel");

        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext context, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            throw new HttpException(0x194,
                string.Format(
                    "The controller for path '{0}' could not be found or it does not implement IController.",
                    context.HttpContext.Request.Path));

        return (IController) _kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}
```

In Global.asax, create your container and register dependencies

```
        Container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());
```

Not the Install(..).  This is a Windsor feature that looks for all "Installers"

```
public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<IController>()
            .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

This "Installer" concept is a Windsor thing.  Note the registration code in it.  You're going to have code that looks like that yo register each interface with it's corresponding service.

and replace the controller factory.

```
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory(Container.Kernel));
```